# Can someone explain the solution to this statement?

Tags: predicate-logic

Say C: set of courses

P(x,y): 'x is a prerequisite for course y'

statement: `'some courses have several prerequisites'`

symbolically:

```
 ∃ x ∈ C, ∃ y ∈ C, ∃ z ∈ C, P(y, x) ∧ P(z, x) ∧ y ≠ z
```

I don't really understand how you get the symbolic expression from the verbal expression.

Also, might there be a simpler way of writing this in logical notation?

In addition!

How would you write this:

```
No course has more than two prerequisites.
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm _surmising_ that what you mean is: How does one get the symbolic expression from the verbal expression.  If that's what you mean, could you make that explicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

$$\exists x\in C\,\exists y\in C\,\exists z\in C\Big(P(y,x)\land P(z,x)\land y\ne z\Big)$$

says that

> there is a course $x$ such that there are courses $y$ and $z$ that are prerequisites for $x$ and are different courses.

In less convoluted language, this says that there is a course $x$ that has at least two prerequisites, here called $y$ and $z$. The $y\ne z$ clause ensures that $y$ and $z$ aren’t just two names for the same course, i.e., that we really do have two prerequisites here, not one with an alias. The word *several* in the original statement is being interpreted as *at least two*. If we defined *several* to mean *at least three*, we’d need a more complicated expression:

$$\exists x\in C\,\exists y\in C\,\exists z\in C\,\exists w\in C\Big(P(y,x)\land P(z,x)\land P(w,x)\land y\ne z\land y\ne w\land z\ne w\Big)$$

Here the $y\ne z\land y\ne w\land z\ne w$ part says that no two of the prerequisites $y,z$, and $w$ are really the same course: we really do have three distinct prerequites here for the course $x$.

Answer (score 1):

"Some courses have several prerequisites"

$\Rightarrow$ " $\exists x \in C$ such that $x$ has several prerequisites"

$\Rightarrow$ " $\exists x \in C$ such that $x$ has at least **two different** prerequisites"

$\Rightarrow$ " $\exists x \in C$, $ \exists y, z \in C$ such that $y \neq z$, $P(y, x) \wedge P(z, x)$ "

$\Rightarrow$ $\exists  x, y, z \in C$,  $y \neq z$, $P(y, x) \wedge P(z, x)$ "

For the second part, using similar reasoning we can symbolically write :

$\nexists x, y, z, w \in C$, $P(y,x) \wedge P(z, x) \wedge P(w, x) \wedge y \neq z \neq w $